# Native Windows CLI tool to show network utilization per IP address

Tags: windows, networking, display, powershell

On Windows: Looking for command line way to extract the instantaneous network throughput (egress and ingress) is being consumed. Information has to be grouped by IP addresses.

It would be similar to Windows' Resource Monitor -> Network -> Network Activity

[Network Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M51xq.png)

Background: We have 20 Windows server that we would like to understand (1) how much network load is it adding to the site, and (2) to which systems it is communicating to/from, by taking instantaneous samples for a period of one month. I don't have access to the router data (e.g. no one knows who supports the router). I understand netsh trace could be an option but analyzing such trace is a bit beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I found on my hard drive a batch file, may be can help you, sorry i don't remember where i got it from ? but anyway, just give a try : Just copy and paste this code below and save it as ***List_Connections.bat*** and execute by double click

```
@echo off
Title List connections
Mode 90,42 & Color 0A
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Log=%~dpn0.txt"
If exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
::Used to convert PID to process names.
for /f "tokens=1 delims=" %%A in ('tasklist') do call :PID %%A

echo [Program:PID]       LocalIP:Port      RemoteIP:Port
(echo [Program:PID]      LocalIP:Port      RemoteIP:Port & echo;)>"%Log%"

echo.
for /f "tokens=1-27 delims=: " %%A in ('netstat -ano') do call :netstat %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E %%F %%G %%H %%I %%J %%K %%L %%M %%N %%O %%P %%Q %%R %%S %%T %%U
start "log" "%Log%"
pause>nul
exit /b

:PID
   set pid_%2=%1
   exit /b

:netstat
set type=%1
set srcIP=%2
set srcPort=%3
set dstIP=%4
set dstPort=%5
set state=%6
set pid=%7
set name=!pid_%pid%!

::Filter local connections away.
if "%state%"=="" exit /b
if not "%type%"=="TCP" exit /b
if "%srcIP%"=="Local" exit /b
if "%dstIP%"=="*" exit /b
if "%srcIP%"=="%dstIP%" exit /b
if "%pid%"=="" exit /b

if "%dstPort%"=="[" (
   set state=LISTENING
   set srcPort=%dstIP%
   set pid=%9
   )
if "%dstPort%"=="[" set name=!pid_%pid%!

if "%name%"=="" set name=Unknown

::Formatting \tabs
set srcPortTab=     %srcPort%
set namePidTab=[%name%:%pid%]                               
set srcIpPortTab=%srcIP%:%srcPort%                               
set dstIpPortTab=%dstIP%:%dstPort%                               
set stateTab=%state%                               
set namePidTab=%namePidTab:~0,20%
set srcIpPortTab=%srcIpPortTab:~0,21%
set dstIpPortTab=%dstIpPortTab:~0,21%
set stateTab=%stateTab:~0,12%
set srcPortTab=%srcPortTab:~-5%

if not "%state%"=="LISTENING" echo.%namePidTab% %srcIPPortTab% %dstIPPortTab% %stateTab%
if "%state%"=="LISTENING" echo.%namePidTab% Listening on: %srcPortTab%

(
    if not "%state%"=="LISTENING" echo.%namePidTab% %srcIPPortTab% %dstIPPortTab% %stateTab%
    if "%state%"=="LISTENING" echo.%namePidTab% Listening on: %srcPortTab%
)>>"%Log%"
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hackoo. Got the script tested - on top of it I also need the current network bandwidth utilization of each connection.